# Configuring dynamic PHPUnit environment variables

Tags: multi-sites, testing

**Current State:**

I'm currently working on running PHPUnit Browser tests in Drupal, and I've successfully configured my phpunit.xml file with these environment variables:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="https://site1.com"/>
<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://db_sitte1:db_sitte1@db_sitte1"/>
```

These settings work well when I run my phpunit.

**Problem:**

Now, I'm working on a multisite project involving multiple sites (site1, site2, site3, site4), and I need to test the functionality on all four of these sites.

**Question:**

How can I dynamically change these two variables in my phpunit.xml file according to the testing code to accommodate a multisite project? like this:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="{DYNAMIC_URL}"/>
<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="{DYNAMIC_DB_CREDENTIALS}"/>
```

Or is there a way to alter this 2 varaible :  **SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL** and **SIMPLETEST_DB**  insidethe setup() method ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a separate phpunit.xml file for each site.
2. Use phpunit's `--configuration` flag to specify
   a configuration file at runtime.